# Pulse Audio EQ Alternative

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, music, equalizer

I have been using ubuntu 14.04 around 3 weeks as my primary os. I'm really into music, i'm using lmms etc.
If i install this eq, it messes up my auto switches between hdmi and audio out and sound is not clear and strong at all. is there any alternatives of that?? it shouldn't be so hard to make another eq. Basically i want something that works just like pulseaudio eq but with a way better sound quality.

Comment: have you checked out this version http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html?

Comment: yeap, it's the only one i have installed, it changes the sound output in order to mess with sound, and it's quality suck

Answer (score 0):

You can use excellent **Pulse Effects**.

Install it via PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects pulseaudio --install-recommends
```

Repository:

https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects

Screenshot:

[image]